# What does an EditText.getText() in android return if it is empty?

Tags: android

I've tried null and empty string, any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code that you had tried?

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString);

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No other possibility.

`getText`, infact, will never return null. It returns `CharSequence` whose contents may be empty.

Instead of doing `getText().toString().equals("")` or vice-versa, it may be faster to do `getText().length() == 0`

Comment: CharSequence is an object reference to some class that implements the interface. Nothing stops the API implementer from returning null from getText, in which case getText().length will cause an NPE.

Comment: Well, CharSequence instance which is returned by getText is never null. Hence my observation.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I have about 20 TextViews in an Activity. In a first step, I set some values to some of them, keeping other untouched. When I iterate through all of them, setting its text to '0' if `getText().length() == 0`, all but one get overwritten with '0' (and it's guaranteed that there is more than one, since I've tested it withouth overwriting with '0'). Same thing by testing `...toString().equals("")`. What could cause this?

Comment: @Valentino Ru, I know this is an old comment, but can you provide an example for which this doesn't work?

Comment: This is already outdated as can be seen here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b102cc24354fb2e44964b60a794746df86be1eb7#diff-d65d9c796a5d459f49303c3e5ac20480

Answer (score 5):

If it's empty, this will work:

```
if(mEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    // stuff to run when it's empty
}
```

Even if it's empty, getText() will still return an Editable, so if you were trying to do this:

```
if(mEditText.getText().equals("")) {
    // stuff
}
```

It most certainly wasn't working.

Answer (score 5):

You can use TextUtils.isEmpty( mEditText.getText().toString() ). It will return true if its empty/null.

Comment: if it returns null, then you'll get a `NullPointerException` doing what you say. Anyways just like @MasterGaurav mentioned, seems that the default EditText will never return null;

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to check it is to stock the value in a var like:

```
String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
```

and then to use boolean operator `isEmpty` like:

```
if (text.isEmpty){
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at several questions and since [it's already possible to get a null](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b102cc24354fb2e44964b60a794746df86be1eb7#diff-d65d9c796a5d459f49303c3e5ac20480) I've found the answer to avoid a

> method invocation toString may produce NPE

warning all over the place:

`String theText = String.valueOf(mEditText.getText());`